# Kivy Crashing w/Image.source = 'filename' using asyncio

Tags: python, image, kivy

I have written a network client in Kivy, and it is working very well.  The network code uses asyncio to watch the network for received objects.  The only Widget that has given problems is the Image().  When setting the image of the image it crashes Kivy completely.  I have found a work around - using Clock.schedule_once.

Here's the loop for detecting what has been sent and taking action (asyncio);

```
async def listen():
    while True:
        for message in CLIENT.get_reader_queue():
            message = loads(message, cls=CustomJSONDecoder)

            if isinstance(message, RPGMenu):
                CLIENT_SCREEN.set_current_menu(message)
                CLIENT_SCREEN.refresh()

                if message.description is None:
                    message.description = '<NO DESCRIPTION FOUND>'

                CLIENT_SCREEN.add_text_item(message.description)
            elif isinstance(message, RPGMessage):
                if message.popup is False:
                    CLIENT_SCREEN.add_text_item(message.text)
                else:
                    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
                    layout.add_widget(Label(text=message.text))
                    button = Button(text='close', size_hint_y=0.25)
                    layout.add_widget(button)

                    popup = Popup(title='Server Message',
                                  content=layout,
                                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400), auto_dismiss=False)
                    button.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

                    popup.open()
            elif isinstance(message, RPGMedia):
                create_popup(message.name, message.text, message.image)
                # THE BELOW WORKS ******
                # Clock.schedule_once(partial(create_popup, message.name, message.text, message.image))
            elif isinstance(message, RPGResultFailure):
                create_popup(message.name, message.description)
            elif isinstance(message, RPGResult):
                CLIENT.result = message
```

In other functions like when I press a button and bring up an image, it works fine but when an RPGMedia object comes in directly and want to display right away it crashes.  The function create_popup creates a simple popup and sets an image.

Please let me know if any more code is required, it quote large with a server side so I thought I would start there.

Here's my **main**;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    CLIENT = Client('127.0.0.1', 9000, loop)

    executer = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

    # asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    # asyncio.ensure_future(console())
    asyncio.ensure_future(listen())

    # MyApp().run()
    loop.run_in_executor(executer, MyApp().run)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.  Since loading pictures takes times, and Kivy won't wait the picture needs to be loaded asynchronously.  Here's an example that I worked with to change the image loading procedure.

Go Kivy!

Original located at; https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.loader.html

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.loader import Loader

class TestApp(App):
    def _image_loaded(self, proxyImage):
        if proxyImage.image.texture:
            self.image.texture = proxyImage.image.texture

    def build(self):
        proxyImage = Loader.image("myPic.jpg")
        proxyImage.bind(on_load=self._image_loaded)
        self.image = Image()
        return self.image

TestApp().run()
```